# Can I give a condition to boolean primitive as initialize?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm not sure it is possible, because I haven't found exact answer, but NetBeans not gives error. But if it's possible, why my code doesn't work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] fiveMatrix = {
        {1, 4, 7, 5, 3}, {3, 7, 9, 10, 1}, {4, -3, 2, -4, 1}, {5, 9, 6, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},};

    System.out.print("Which line do you want to write out (0-4)? ");
    int lineNumber = scan.nextInt();
    boolean goodLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
    if (goodLine) {
        while (goodLine) {
            System.out.println("Bad index.");
            System.out.print("Which line do you want to write out (0-4)? ");
            lineNumber = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "doesn't work"? It's hard to tell without an error message or stacktrace.

Comment: Add  `goodLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;` inside `while` loop to exit.

Comment: @secretsuperstar That looks like a simple solution, but it is conceptually wrong: you do not duplicate code, even when it is just a single line. Because you would then have to remember that you have to update each duplicate of your check when the condition needs to adapted. Duplicating code is always the first step to introduce future bugs.

Comment: @dave you're right. I didn't mentioned the error message. It went into an infinite loop. And later I removed the if condition but that also didn't help.

Comment: @GhostCat thank you for your notes. I'm working on understand the answers. :) I'am totally a newbie. Of course I'm going to accept one of the solutions.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here:

```
boolean goodLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
```

is evaluated **once**, and the result is assigned to that variable.

Later changes to `lineNumber = scan.nextInt();` do **not** change that boolean variable!

The "correct" solution: you have to recompute the boolean property. But ideally not by copying code, but by creating a small helper method:

```
boolean isGoodLine(int lineNumber) { return lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4; }
```

And now, instead of having a boolean variable in your other code, you simply invoke that method whenever the lineNumber changes!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to update the boolean inside the loop, to avoid infinite loop.

```
boolean badLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
while (badLine) {
    System.out.println("Bad index.");
    System.out.print("Which line do you want to write out (0-4)? ");
    lineNumber = scan.nextInt();
    badLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
}
```

I renamed the `boolean`, since its original name was confusing. I also eliminated the `if` condition, since it's redundant.

Comment: Thank you. The rename suggestion is relly justifiable. And I really forget to say to the while loop to examine the condition every time.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a line inside while loop

```
boolean goodLine = lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
```

Consider refactor to a method to avoid duplicate code:

```
public boolean goodLine(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.print("Which line do you want to write out (0-4)? ");
    int lineNumber = scan.nextInt();
    return lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > 4;
}
```

And call it:

```
while(goodLine());
```

Consider also call it a `badLine` because user input is wrong (not 0-4 values)

Comment: Thank you. Perfect solution. I choosen the other one because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code and easy to understand

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Post3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] fiveMatrix = {
            {1, 4, 7, 5, 3}, {3, 7, 9, 10, 1}, {4, -3, 2, -4, 1}, {5, 9, 6, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},};

        System.out.println("Which line do you want to write out (0-4)? ");
        int input = -1;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("input valid number between 0 to 4");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            if(input >= 0 && input <= 4) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("input is "+input);
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Close good. Thank you. Your solution brings a new idea. On the other hand doesn't handle the first data request. And if would handle, it'll be a code duplication what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: It does handle. it will continue until user inputs a valid input! do you want to take two inputs?

Comment: I wasn't precise in my wording. I need a 'System.out.println("Bad index.");' error code in the case of bad number (as it has inside the question) . And if I use inside the while loop, it'll been read out, whether the answer is good or not. That's why I need the data request before the loop.